# How to write a simple MPS file to submit to NEOS servers

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, neos-server, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to find an open source lp solver that is fast enough to my problem. I'm trying to build a MPS file so I can submit it to NEOS servers and compare the performance of different solvers.

My problem involves, at its most difficult cases, something around 150 integer variables but I'm starting with a simple case to help me figure out how the MPS file format works.

This is the problem:

```
minimize  : 330.3 * M1 + 1132.88 * M2 + 955.86 * M3
subject to:
         20 <= 60 * M2 <= 20.9
         20 <= 34 * M3 <= 20.9
         M1 + M2 + M3 = 1
```

and I wrote the following MPS file:

```
NAME problema1
ROWS
 L  K
 L  N
 E  ONE
 N  CUSTO
COLUMNS
    M1        ONE       1              CUSTO     330.3
    M2        K         60
    M2        ONE       1              CUSTO     1132.88
    M3        N         34
    M3        ONE       1              CUSTO     955.86
RHS
    KLESS     K         20.9
    NLESS     N         20.9
    ONEREST   ONE       1
RANGES
    RANGE1    K         0.9
    RANGE2    N         0.9
ENDATA
```

Using the linear solvers available at NEOS (https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html), just Gurobi can solve it. The others find the problem is infeasible (which it's not).

I'm pretty confident that this is a problem with my MPS file, but I just can't figure it out what it is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe add some more background. If you are only looking for some open-source solver for MIP-problems, there are not many candidates: Coin CBC, GLPK and lpsolve (in this order for me) as free software and SCIP (open-source but non-free; may even beat CBC). Remark: there is a large gap between open-source and commercial solvers (like Gurobi, CPLEX and Mosek). Also check out [those benchmarks](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/milpc.html). If you really want to do all these benchmarks, why not use one of those to generate those standardized MPS-files (GLPK maybe having the best docs)?

Comment: NEOS for some solvers also accepts .lp format, which is more human readable than .mps.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @sascha I know about the gap between open-source and commercial solvers. However, commercial solvers are very expensive when you need to scale the solution to a great number of users, which is my case. I think that, for the size of my problem, an open-source solver like those you cited can do the trick.

Comment: Thank @RichL However, I'm interest in the Cbc solver, for which NEOS server doesn't accept the .lp format as input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed your MPS file has a problem. The lines in the RHS section should have one name e.g.

```
RHS
    RHS1      K         20.9
    RHS1      N         20.9
    RHS1      ONE       1
```

Basically the solver picks one RHS set. Similar for the RANGES section. I am not sure what you intended using the lines in the RANGES section.

Comment: Thanks Erwin! That solved my problem =) The RANGES section is to point out the >= constraint to the indicated rows. So, row K will be between 20.9 and 20 (20.9 specified in the RHS section - 0.9 specified in the RANGES section). Same for row N

Comment: Yep, I missed that <= part (it was late)

Comment: How would you add the integer constraints on variables M1, M2 and M3?

Comment: Integer variables can be specified through UI in the BOUNDS section or using INTORG/INTEND. Check the documentation for your solver.

Comment: It seems that different solvers have different behaviors for this. But I was able to solve my problem using LI constraints. Thank you!